Flutter Payment Gateway Integration: "10002 Merchant Authentication Failed" in CCAvenue
I am trying to integrate the CCAvenue payment gateway into my Flutter application. However, I am facing an issue where I get the following error:
10002 Merchant Authentication Failed

What I Have Tried:

I researched this error and found a [video](provide link if available) that suggests adding plugins for CCAvenue. However, the video is based on WordPress, not Flutter.
I received the Mobile Integration Kit from CCAvenue, but I am unsure how to use it effectively in a Flutter application.

My Questions:

How can I properly integrate the CCAvenue payment gateway into my Flutter app?
Are there any Flutter plugins or libraries available for CCAvenue integration?
Am I potentially missing a step or doing something incorrectly during the integration process?

Additional Notes:

I have already verified my Merchant ID and Working Key.
I suspect that my implementation might be missing some steps required for Flutter-specific integration.

If anyone has successfully integrated CCAvenue with Flutter, or if there’s any resource or documentation that could guide me, please share your insights.
